# How to use FileOpen function with ReadWrite mode in PowerBuilder

Tags: file, file-handling, powerbuilder, read-write

Is there anyway I can use FileOpen function for ReadWrite mode in PowerBuilder?

I want to use same File Handle for both read and write operations but FileOpen has no such mode.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the FileOpen method, the handle to the file is returned.  You can then use that handle in both the FileReadEx and FileWriteEx methods to read and write to the specified file.

The PB Fileopen method is essentially a wrapper for the Windows Createfile function but hasn't really changed over the decades.  I believe you want to use the FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED option for asynchronous I/O but the PB method does not support that.  Basically if you wish to read a file then write to it in PB you need to Fileopen, Read, Fileclose then Fileopen, Write, Fileclose.

Comment: The 3rd optional parameter to the FileOpen function is fileaccess and can be set to either Read! or Write! where Read! means Read-only access and Write! means Write-only access. There is no other option for fileaccess parameter. in other words there is no way a file can be opened in both read and write mode at the same time.  That is what  PowerBuilder help tells me and first thing first how do i open file? Do you mean if i open file in write-only mode then FileReadEx will let me read the file with same file handle without closing it? That makes no sense to me. Please explain a bit more.